# How can I increment the numerical part of a string?

Tags: python

I have a string like this:

```
location = "IP.Location.1"
```

and there are other locations like `IP.Location.2`, `IP.Location.3`, etc.

How can I increment the location from `IP.Location.2` to `IP.Location.3`?  I always need to increment the numerical part by 1.

Comment: Did you try splitting your string by "."? Then you can concatenate the first two entries in your split (with "." inbetween) and additionally to a str() of your number that you increment

Comment: Strings are immutable in python. But there are ways around it so that you can modify a string. One way would be to make the string a list and then replace the last item with the incremental number

Comment: @MEKH do you want to take a string like `"IP.Location.1"` as *input* and create the corresponding string `"IP.Location.2"` as *output*, or do you want to take a number like 5 as input and create the corresponding string `"IP.Location.5"` as output?

Comment: Doesn't matter, the answers explain almost every combo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s a generic solution that does exactly what you asked for, i.e. incrementing an integer number at the end of a string that is separated by a dot.

```
location = "IP.Location.1"

parts = location.rsplit(".", 1)
parts[1] = str(int(parts[1]) + 1)
location = ".".join(parts)

print (location)
# --> IP.location.2
```

Comment: what about increment the location which is outside the string

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t get what you mean.

Comment: the value that saved the string

Comment: I’m very sorry, but I still don’t understand. Maybe give an example?

Comment: I want to save each value in location1 = "IP.Location.1" 
location2 = "IP.Location.2"

Comment: It probably makes more sense to use a list instead of separate variables, i.e. `locations = ["IP.Location.1", "IP.Location.2"]`.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways to achieve this but this would be an easy way if you are pre Python 3.6:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    print('IP.Location.{my_number}'.format(my_number=i))
```

If you have Python 3.6+ then:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(f'IP.Location.{i}')
```

Finally if you just have the string and you want to increment up from it then extract the int from the string, extract just the non-int bit and use that as your string and range:

```
location = "IP.Location.1"
initial_number = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, location)))
string_phrase = ''.join([i for i in location if not i.isdigit()])

for i in range(initial_number, initial_number + 10):
    print(f'{string_phrase}{i}')
```

Comment: That last piece of code won’t work if <IP> is not the literal string “IP”, but an actual IP number (dotted quad).

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns with an ambiguous question. Between the various answers the OP has likely got a solution which is the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python 3.6 + solution:

```py
for i in range(10):
    print(f'IP.Location.{i + 1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the strings? See code below.

```
# create base string
location = "IP.Location."
# introduce counting variable
count = 1
# create empty list to store results
ip_locs = []

# loop to get incremented strings
for i in range(10):
    ip_loc = location + str(count)
    ip_locs.append(ip_loc)
    count = count+1

print(ip_locs)
```